# RESTFull Service : Jersey 2.8 Package import error in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, rest, jakarta-ee, jersey, jax-rs

I use Eclipse Kepler version, Tomcat 6, JDK 1.8. 
I add the jars inside `JAXRS-ri` which was downloaded from [here](https://jersey.java.net/download.html).

**Jars are :**

> jersey-client.jar, jersey-common.jar,  jersey-container-servlet.jar, 
>   jersey-container-servlet-core.jar,  jersey-server.jar.

Once those jars were added into build path in eclipse, and import them (javax.ws) in my java class

```
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
```

It gives error as they are not found, then I added Jersey 1.8 jars. Then it worked well. But for 2.8 jars, it doesn't work. How can I use 2.8 jars? I am still new to Jersey and please let me know where is the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you added the JAR named `javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.jar` (in the `ext` folder)?
It should contain those imports.